# Sending message to Team chat using c# application system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Currently I'm using the way of Microsoft Graph API beta you can send a message in a chat to write the application but I face these errors **The type or namespace ChatMessage could not be found**,  **The name authProvider does not exist in the current context**, **The await operator can only be used within an async modifier and changing its return type to tásk** and **Microsoft.GraphGraphServiceClient does not contain a definition for Chat and no extension method Chats accepting a first argument of type Microsoft.Graph.Graph.ServiceClient could be found.** Can anyone help me to solve it.

Error
[image]

Thanks a lot .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace w
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(**authProvider**);

            var chatMessage = new **ChatMessage**
            {
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    Content = "Hello world"
                }
            };

            *await* graphClient.**Chats**["19:056680e9-868a-49a2-bf96-2ba2d2c39b5d_76ff09a8-7650-426d-843b-3d1104128f25@unq.gbl.spaces"].Messages
      .Request()
      .AddAsync(chatMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta?tabs=CS) use `using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;` instead of `using Microsoft.Graph;`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
```

Comment: it come out the error of the type or namespace name'Beta' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph' but I have already install NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Beta -Version 0.9.0-preview .Can i know what is the reason for the error

Answer (score 0):

It's true that we'd better not to use Beta version api but actually [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request) had beta version, so using beta version shouldn't lead to the exception.

According to your error message, `The name authProvider does not exist in the current context`, so it seems that you misunderstood the `authProvider` mentioned in the api. There's a [hyper link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS).

[image]

About the `authProvider`, that's the object contianing the authorization information. `await* graphClient.**Chats**["19.....` is calling the ms graph api, and we need the access token in the request header to call the api right? But now since you are using the graph SDK, so you only need to prepare the authProvider.

AuthProvider is something contained in Azure AD, and Azure AD offers you 2 kinds of flows, one for users sign in first to get the authorization, so you have to provide a sign in page in this scenarion, for example `Authorization code provider`. Another one for applications so there's no users sign in, you have to create an azure ad application then get a application client secret to valid the aad application in your own code, this is known as `Client credentials provider`. But `Client credentials provider` is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) for this api.

So you may follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) to create Auth code provider.

[image]

Comment: thanks , currently i stuck at NuGet\Install-Package Azure.Identity -Version 1.0.0-preview.1 .It since like VS2013 does not know anything about netstandard is that possible for me to install it

Comment: can you install it via VS `Manage Nuget Packages..` page?

Comment: can't it appears the error like the image above

Comment: what kind of project you have now? Isn't it an asp.net core project?

Comment: Nope, it isn't. it is a window form application project

Comment: I'm afraid you need to use `Microsoft.Identity.Client` package for your project. Since I don't know familiar with winform, I can only try to find a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnet-desktop-tutorial/tree/master/1-Calling-MSGraph/1-1-AzureAD), hope it can help.